# Ruby on Rails - JQuery does not work properly even though it works "external"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, togglebutton

this might be a bit of a Ruby on Rails beginners question - i created some easy JQuery Code.

```
$("input[id^='show_Fulltext']").click(function(){
$("#Fulltext".concat($(this).val())).toggle();
});
```

Then i added some HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='2' id='show_Fulltext2'></input> 
<input type='button' value='1' id='show_Fulltext1'></input>  
<div id="Fulltext1" style="display:none;">Substring 1</div>
<div id="Fulltext2" style="display:none;">Substring 2</div>
```

Now the result are divs which i can toggle on or off.
https://jsfiddle.net/z1w1p3o1/71/

This works perfectly and the why i want it to work (EXTERNAL).

Next i tried to make this code work in my Ruby on Rails application. I have to add that i did not create the project, so there is already JQuery used in the project but i do not understand why this JQuery already existing works, and mine is not working:

I edited the application.js file now like in the following (basically i copied my code into it):

```
$(function() {
/*
 $('#content_main th a, #content_main .pagination a',).live('click', function(){
  $.getScript(this.href);
   return false;
  });
*/

  $('#search input').keyup(function() {
    $.get($('#search').attr('action'), $('#search').serialize(), null,'script');
    return false;
  });

 $('#search2 input').keyup(function() {
    $.get($('#search2').attr('action'), $('#search2').serialize(), null,'script');
    return false;
  });


  $('#search select').change(function() {
    $.get($('#search').attr('action'), $('#search').serialize(), null,'script');
    return false;
  });

  //$('#search :radio').change(function() {
    $('#search :radio').change(function() {
    $.get($('#search').attr('action'), $('#search').serialize(), null,'script');
    return false;
  });
  // HERE IS THE CODE I COPIED!! -----------
  $("input[id^='show_Fulltext']").click(function(){
   $("#Fulltext".concat($(this).val())).toggle();
  });
  //-------------------------------------

  $('#initiation_planned').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  $('#initiation').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  $('#first_recruitment').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  $('#last_recruitment').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  $('#lock_planned').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  $('#arch_end').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
  $('#lock').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Now if i edit the HTML in my Ruby on RAILS project as shown above (working externally in the editor), the buttons do not toggle the divs. I assume the whole JS is not working. I edited a file where working JS code is already incorporated. Any ideas where i might have done a mistake?   `

Comment: Ok sorry for bothering - i could easily fix it. I just had to compile the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing without ID's pretty easily.

```js
$('.module').on('click', 'button', function(){
  var $self = $(this);
  var $txt = $self.siblings('.full-text').eq($self.index());
  $txt.toggle();
});
```

```css
.full-text { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="module">
  <button>Show 1</button>
  <button>Show 2</button>
  <div class="full-text">Full text 1</div>
  <div class="full-text">Full text 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It works. Now i got another problem with JQuery. I try to explain it. The given code / divs etc. is the result of a search. The results are large DIVs with Texts. With the buttons i can enlarge or shorten the texts. This works for me if i show all the initial results. But if i filter the results with JQuery with the functions above in the Jquery-Skript i posted, then the toggle skript does not work anymore. I am kinda clueless why this is happening. So maybe i have to serialize the toggle skript also, but i am not sure how to do it in this case.

Comment: Ask a new question instead please.